# Reduce function to calculate sum of each column

Tags: c++, opencv

I got stuck with OpenCV while trying to calculate the sum of each column for a thresholded (binary) image.

This code

```
Mat thrs;
threshold(roi, thrs, 252, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
Mat dy;
reduce(thrs, dy, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM);
```

gives me a runtime error stating

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats
```

I assume this is due to the binary image being in CV_8UC1 format, therefore dy is in the same format and cannot hold the summed up values. Is this correct? Whats the way around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you not specify the last parameter `dtype` and destination matrix is not initialized [`cv::reduce`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) will assume that `dtype` equal to type of source matrix. In your case it will be `CV_8UC1`. Since this format can't store summed values you got the runtime error.

So to avoid this error you need to specify `dtype` parameter. For example:

```
reduce(thrs, dy, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32SC1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The reduce function supports only `32S` `32F` and `64F` as Output. This is not in the documentation of the [`reduce`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) function... but it is like that... by default it will try to take the same type as the input. So, you may try doing something like this:

```
cv::reduce(thrs, dy, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32S);
```

just a reminder:

```
32S is int
32F is float
64F is float
```